# Why is my "ls -A" displaying current and parent directory (even if should not?)

Tags: bash, centos, ls

I'm writing a little bash script.
As written in the reference:
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html

```
ls -A
```

Should not list "./" and "../" directories.
But... on my system (centOS) is still listing it.
Is there some option "always on" I should be take care of before running this script?

Comment: What does `type -a ls` print? You probably have `ls` defined as a function or alias.

Comment: It display this:

`type -a ls
ls is aliased to /bin/ls $LS_OPTIONS'
ls is /bin/ls`  and `echo $LS_OPTIONS` show:

--color=tty -F -a -b -T 0

Comment: (Use backticks, not "[code]".) That explains it `$LS_OPTIONS` must contain `-a`, which causes `.` and `..` to be listed. If you want more information, post a new question to [unix.se].

Comment: But this is the right answer... the problem is that I didn't check aliases of the command... you are right! I can call the command from it's original path in order to avoid the us of the $LS_OPTIONS

Comment: Or type `\ls`, or remove the alias.